# What are some good examples of open-source articles in which the synergy of two medicines is demonstrated?

Tags: pharmacology, theoretical-biology, medicine

I am doing research on Stochastic Cooperative Game Theory (a subfield in mathematics), which I will henceforth call SCGT for convenience. In this theory, entities can work together to receive a bigger combined payoff than they would otherwise receive if they had not worked together. 
In the stochastic version of cooperative game theory, the payoffs are not deterministic, but follow a probability distribution.

It seemed to me I could apply this theory to drug synergy. If there is drug synergy, there is a (high) chance that two medicines combined are better at healing a patient than just multiplying the dosage of either medicine by $2$. With SCGT, I could determine how much each medicine contributes to the healing of the patient, if some information is known about the drug-response curves. This in turn could tell us something about how much the manufacturers of each drug receive to be paid (in theory).

However, I am not quite well-acquainted with the literature on drug synergy. Furthermore, I can't access many articles on the topic without paying a lot (as I'm with the mathematics department at the university, I can't view articles on biology for free).

So my questions are:

> 1. Do you know any open-source articles in which it is shown that two drugs work in synergy according to the Bliss Independence model?

and:

> 2. Do you know any open-source articles in which it is shown that three or more drugs work in synergy according to the Bliss Independence model?

The same questions apply to the Loewe additivity framework.

Comment: This list is about biology, not about literature. It is valid to ask for examples of studies on the topic that interests you, but not, in my opinion, about articles in a particular type of journal. An good answer describing and referencing such studies would be of general interest here. An answer with [a mere reference would not be suitable](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). The type of the journal (open access, written in English etc.) is no concern of biology.